# In Mongo DB , How to get the inital date of data insertion

Tags: mongodb-query

I entered many data in MongoDB on different dates,
 for example
from January, each day I entered data, how to know which date I started data insertion process

Comment: Are you using the `ObjectId` on mongo as an identifier?

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is no way to find that out, a workaround for that is you can alter your table and add a `timestamp` column, with default value `now()`.

That let you see when future inserts are created.